# Any simple recommendations for creating a Password Salt and Hashing it?

Tags: c#, .net, passwords, hash, salt

wondering if anyone has some quick links to code snippets to generate a random salt (that's not easy too easy to guess) and then hashing some plain text password with the generated hash.

Suggestions or links, please?

.NET code, please.

Comment: It does not matter if your salt is easy to guess. It is somehow appended to the password to decrease the effectiveness of dictionary attacks and rainbow tables. It should be complex and probably random, however, as you seem to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The salt can be know. Why would you want the salt "not easy to guess"? It just has to be unique so that if two people share the same password the salt applied to the password ensures that they don't end up with the same hash value and to reduce the effectiveness of Rainbow attacks (where a reverse Hash dictionary is used to see the possible plain text value(s) that can produce a particular hash value)

From a code snippet on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649202.aspx#secnetht03_step3):

```
private static string CreateSalt(int size)
{
  // Generate a cryptographic random number using the cryptographic
  // service provider
  RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
  byte[] buff = new byte[size];
  rng.GetBytes(buff);
  // Return a Base64 string representation of the random number
  return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
}
```

You can then append or prepend this on to the plain text password, then hash it.

Comment: There is a special method for hashing Password+salt,  DIY is fatal in security.

Comment: Updated for a cryptographically secure random number. However, since a salt can be known (it is stored in plain text usually, so no matter how cryptographically random its generation is it should be treated as public information) the randomness is not as importance. Its uniqueness is.

Comment: Calm down and look up PasswordDeriveBytes()

Comment: @Pure, are you familiar with "send me the codez pleaz" meme? Look it up.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - *massive sigh* if u want to start trollin' like that, you can say that lots of SO is just 'send me the codez' .. *sigh sigh sigh* There's always one troll around here :( No - I'm not after a quick fix / let someone else do it. I was hoping i'd get a link to a post that would explain some code AND WHY that code is actually worth using. Eg. User `GetNonZeroBytes` instead of `GetBytes`. Somepeople suggest to always use `GetBytes` instead.. So i'm hoping for more than just show me da codez.

Comment: @Pure: It's not just What you ask but also How you ask. The second part of that comment would be a nice replacement for ".NET code, please."